# Oracle SQL procedure MAX, MIN, AVG of set of values

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, max, min

I've created this procedure:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sales_period (
   purchdate1 IN DATE,
   purchdate2 IN DATE
)
IS 
    CURSOR purchcur IS
    SELECT purchases.purchdate, max(purchases.purchprice) max1, 
           min(purchases.purchprice) min1, avg(purchases.purchprice) avg1
    FROM purchases
    WHERE purchases.purchdate BETWEEN sales_period.purchdate1 AND 
          sales_period.purchdate2
    group by purchases.purchdate;
    purchrow purchcur%ROWTYPE;
    e_foreign_key_error EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (e_foreign_key_error, -2291);
BEGIN
 OPEN purchcur;
  LOOP
   FETCH purchcur INTO purchrow;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Sales report: ');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Date sold: ' || purchrow.purchdate);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Max saleprice: ' || purchrow.max1);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Avg saleprice: ' || purchrow.avg1);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Min saleprice: ' || purchrow.min1);
   EXIT WHEN purchcur%NOTFOUND;
  END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN e_foreign_key_error THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('no existing field in parent table');
  CLOSE purchcur;
 END;
/
```

What I want to do is enter in two dates, and then it prints out the sales report i.e max, avg, and min prices during that period (between the two dates entered). So, the thing is that what I have done does this:

```
SQL> exec sales_period('1-Jun-15', '30-Aug-15');
Sales report:
Date sold: 03-JUL-15
Max saleprice: 1600
Avg saleprice: 1600
Min saleprice: 1600
Sales report:
Date sold: 05-JUL-15
Max saleprice: 5000
Avg saleprice: 5000
Min saleprice: 5000
Sales report:
Date sold: 10-AUG-15
Max saleprice: 3000
Avg saleprice: 3000
Min saleprice: 3000
Sales report:
Date sold: 02-JUN-15
Max saleprice: 2000
Avg saleprice: 2000
Min saleprice: 2000
Sales report:
Date sold: 07-JUL-15
Max saleprice: 1500
Avg saleprice: 1500
Min saleprice: 1500
```

What I am wanting it to do is get ALL the prices between those dates, and figure out the max, min and avg and display it only once. So like, lets say...

01-Jul-2015 it has a saleprice of 1000

02-Jul-2015 has a saleprice of 1300

28-Jul-2015 has a saleprice of 1500

I do `exec sales_period('1-Jul-15', '30-Jul-15');`

I am wanting it to print out like this:

`Max: 1500, min: 1000, avg: 1300`

Not like what it is doing when I run it - where it does it for each date, and doesn't get the min, max and avg **overall**. I'm wanting it to get the overall min, max and avg.

I would love some help with this! - thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to group by the purchase_date because you have multiple dates within your range, hence your multiple results.

I'm also a bit unsure about the exception you have defined.

The following seems to me to be more what you might want;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sales_period (
   purchdate1 IN DATE,
   purchdate2 IN DATE
)
IS 
    l_max_price    NUMBER;
    l_min_price    NUMBER;
    l_avg_price    NUMBER

BEGIN

   SELECT max(purchases.purchprice) max1, 
          min(purchases.purchprice) min1,
          avg(purchases.purchprice) avg1
   INTO   l_max_price,
          l_min_price,
          l_avg_price        
    FROM purchases
    WHERE purchases.purchdate BETWEEN purchdate1 AND purchdate2;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Sales report: ');
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Date range sold: ' || TO_CHAR(purchdate1,'DD-MON-YYYY')|| ' TO ' || TO_CHAR(purchdate2,'DD-MON-YYYY'));
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Max saleprice: ' || l_max_price);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Avg saleprice: ' || l_avg_price);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Min saleprice: ' || l_min_price);

EXCEPTION
  WHEN no_data_found THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('no data for the date range');
END;
/
```

Please note that I haven't actually run/compiled this so it may well have the odd syntax issue but the principle stands.